# Under what conditions are there only finite number of distinct subsets S of W such that S generated W?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let W be the subspace of vector space V. Under what conditions are there only finite number of distinct subsets S of W such that S generates W?

I took $W$ to be $XY$ Plane. Now there are infinitely many subsets of $XY$ plane which generate it. For example we can take {$(0,n),(n,0)$} and n runs through natural numbers. But when will there be finite number of subsets?

Please give me hints

Thanks for stopping by

Comment: Do you mean "Under what circumstances does the vector space $W$ have only finitely many spanning sets?" If so, then I don't see how $V$ enters in the question, and if you insist that $W$ is over the reals, then the only possibility is $W=\{0\}$.

Comment: @DanielLittlewood i guess this is what question asks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then the following should answer it.

> Claim: If $V$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space with non-zero, finite dimension, then $V$ has infinitely many distinct spanning sets.
>
> Proof: Let $S=\{v_{1},\ldots v_{n}\}$ be a spanning set of $V$. Choose $S$ to be linearly independent (why can we?). Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R} \setminus  \{0\}$. Then the set $\{\lambda v_{1},\ldots,\lambda v_{n}\}$ also spans $V$.

Comment: But question is under what conditions we can have finite number of distinct spanning sets'

Comment: And you conclude that the only such vector space is $\{0\}$.